# AEM / Sightly / HTL: Is it possible to use the parents _cq_template when calling that component via data-sly-resource?

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I have a basic component lets call it a 'label component' and in this 'label component' we're using a 'heading component' which uses a forceTemplateValues.html file and a cq_template > .content.xml to set the dialog parameters. That works fine.

However, I have another component that calls the label component via data-sly-resource and unfortunately the .content.xml templating values aren't being passed as well, so the author is having to manually set these parameters constantly.

Is it possible to have those templating dialog parameters passed via data-sly-resource where you don't have to have another _cq_template > .content.xml file to support?

I apologize for any confusion ahead of time on my part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

'cq_template' is used only when you adding a new component into your page. It copies 'cq_template' content into your resource. It works in similar way as page templates.

So in your case you have to have _cq_template > .content.xml for 'another component'.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="my/another/component">
    <label
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="my/label/component"
        someProperty="myPropertyValue" />
</jcr:root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within AEM only the parent will inherit those templating parameters, so they cannot be passed to duplicates via `data-sly-resource` without also including those same duplicate templating parameters within your new component.